# Unpinned Windows Explorer in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, taskbar

I accidently unpinned the Windows Explorer icon on my desktop task bar in Windows 8 and cannot find any possible way to reverse this. What must I do to get Windows Explorer back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start the Explorer, make a rightclick on the taskbar icon and select "pin to taskbar"

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Start screen, right-click free area or press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to display commands bar on the bottom.
2. Click **All Apps**.
3. Scroll the list until you see **File Explorer**.
4. Right-click its tile, and click **Pin to taskbar** command on the bottom bar.

Or just start Explorer with <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, right-click its icon and click **Pin to taskbar** as [suggested by magicandre1981](https://superuser.com/a/537545/80304).